# Showing that a subset is a sublattice or not?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, lattice-orders

If $B$ is a lattice, then its Cartesian product with itself is also a lattice.

Now consider $[B]^2=\{(a,b):a\le b\}$, which is a subset of the Cartesian product of $B$ with itself, $B\times B$. Now the problem is how to show that $[B]^2$ is a sublattice of $B\times B$.

It is clear that $[B]^2$ is a lattice, but I have problems in showing that the $\sup$ and $\inf$ of its elements are same as in its super-set $B\times B$.

Comment: Can you explain more clearly what difficulty you have in showing the *meet* and *join* of [B]^2 agree with $B\times B$ ?

Comment: This is a valid concern, but I'm suggesting you include this in the body of your Question for the sake of Readers who look there to understand how to help you.  If you prefer, I will edit your Question for you.

Comment: Sup and inf should be same as in cartesian product of B for any two elements but I dont know how to show that.

Comment: I understand what you are saying.  I'm encouraging you to edit the body of your Question.  If you wish, I will include that clarification in an edit of your Question.

Comment: Yeah sure you may edit.

Answer (score 2):

If $(a_1,b_1),(a_2,b_2)\in[B]^2$, then from
$$a_1 \leq b_1 \quad\text{ and }\quad a_2\leq b_2$$
it follows that 
$$a_1\wedge a_2 \leq b_1\wedge b_2 \quad\text{ and }\quad a_1\vee a_2 \leq b_1\vee b_2.$$
Thus, $(a_1\wedge a_2,b_1\wedge b_2), (a_1\vee a_2,b_1\vee b_2) \in [B]^2$, these being the meet and the join of the pairs in $B^2$.